# Clarification in declaring an array

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);
/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[])
{
  int i, c;
  while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
    ;
  s[1] = '\0';
  if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
    return c; /* not a number */
  i = 0;
  if (isdigit(c)) /* collect integer part */
  while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
    ;
  if (c == '.') /* collect fraction part */
    while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
      ;
  s[i] = '\0';
  if (c != EOF)
    ungetch(c);
  return NUMBER;
}
```

```
#define BUFSIZE 100
char buf[BUFSIZE];  /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0;       /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void)     /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) /* push character back on input */
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

The above code is from K&R.

In the above code, I see the array `buf[]` is used to a maximum of index 1, but it is defined to have a size of 100.  Is the definition ok or there is a huge wastage in memory?

I pretty much think this is a bad style of programming.

I'm asking for getop() func only,not for general getch() and ungetch()

I'm a beginner and I'm sorry if my question is invalid :P

Comment: "*I see the array buf[ ] is used to a maximum of index 1*" -- Where?

Comment: What if you call `ungetch` 2 or more times? So no, it is not waste of memory? This allows ungetting all the character back into buffer.

Comment: Mohit Jain and Cool Guy, forgive me for not posting full code.Now it's updated with full code

Comment: If only `getop()` is used, then you could argue 1 byte will be enough ... I wouldn't go as far as saying 100 bytes is a *huge* waste of memory, though.

Comment: I think you are supposed to assume that the `getch` and `ungetch` functions might be used by other code in the program too, so that there are already chars ungetch'd by the time this function is called

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the "*style of programming*", these are functions without anything to run them (ie. a `main` function). As such, you can't tell how these ***will be used*** but you can understand how they ***can be used***. Now, suppose `ungetch` is called in a loop, without `getch` being called at all. In each iteration, `bufp` will grow by 1, and `buf` will slowly fill up to the point where `bufp` is equal to `BUFSIZE` and the "too many characters" will be printed. Next, if `getch` is called in a loop *AFTER* `buf` is full, `bufp` will shrink by 1 for each iteration untill `buf` is empty and `getchar` will be used for the next character.

Comment: Yeah, so the whole buffer is in fact used, or it might be used depending on how `getch` and `ungetch` and called.  The OP's claim that only two bytes are used is wrong.